# where add a WooCommerce script for product variation?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I'm trying to add a script to php/Woocommerce (theme: customify) because beyond 20 product variation, I cannot add more.

My question is : where add the script and what is the script ?

I found some informations but not the solution. I tried this one :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_meta_boxes_variations_per_page', 'handsome_bearded_guy_increase_variations_per_page' );
function handsome_bearded_guy_increase_variations_per_page() {
    return 50;
}
```

but no results.

Comment: Custom hooked functions code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Or you can also use [Code Snippets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) Wordpress plugin

Comment: Thank you. And can I push my code directly in the active theme or on a specific line in functions.php ?

Comment: Be more explicit: what code? what do you plan to do? Provide the related code in your question too…

Comment: ok, in fact I would like to know how to modify function.php when variations do not exist. In order not to appear. But I don't know where I can do that. Thanks for your answer.